# Type safety of indexed columns in an in-memory database

Tags: c#, indexing, api-design, in-memory-database

Root of the problem: I want to design a database entity member indexing API that does not require repetition in the model definition and maintains a reasonable level of type safety.

Drawn-out explanation: I have a basic in-memory database of people. Each person has a full name and the key of their favorite celebrity in the table.

```
public class IMDB
{
    public Dictionary<int, Person> people;
}

public class Person
{
    public string firstname;
    public string lastname;
    public int favoriteCelebrityID;
}
```

Now celebrities want to be able to quickly find their fans through `favoriteCelebrityID`. An index is obvious, and thinking to the future, I made this interface:

```
public class IMDB
{
    public Dictionary<int, Person> people;

    private Dictionary<object, Dictionary<int, int>> _rowContents;
    private Dictionary<object, Dictionary<int, List<int>>> _rowIndex;

    // Returns the ID field in the given row.
    public int RelatedID(int rowID, object field) { ... }

    // Returns the ID of each rows with the given key in its field.
    public List<int> IDRelatedIDs(int key, object field) { ... }

    // Setter for the field. Maintains the index.
    public void SetRelatedID(int rowID, int key, object field) { ... }
}

public class Person
{
    public enum IndexedFields
    {
        FavoriteCelebrityID
    }

    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
}
```

The benefits I saw:

- Static type safety at the API level, aside from passing in `object`.
- Easy to make an enum for indexed keys in any new tables.
- No field names repeated in the `Person` model.

But now I need to index the string `lastName` too, so I can find families. This is where I'm stuck. My best idea is to implement a triplet of index methods for each data type:

```
public class IMDB
{
    ...
    public int IDRelatedID(int rowID, object field) { ... }
    public List<int> IDRelatedIDs(int key, object field) { ... }
    public void SetRelatedID(int rowID, int key, object field) { ... }

    public string IDRelatedString(int rowID, object field) { ... }
    public List<int> StringRelatedIDs(string key, object field) { ... }
    public void SetRelatedString(int rowID, string key, object field) { ... }
}

public class Person
{
    public enum IndexedIDs
    {
        FavoriteCelebrityID
    }

    public enum IndexedStrings
    {
        LastName
    }

    public string firstName;
}
```

But now there's the potential to accidentally put an `IndexedStrings` entry into `IDRelatedID`, which can only be detected at runtime.

**Is there a way to expose a member indexing API that:**

- Does not require repetition in the model definitions?
- Maintains a reasonable level of type safety?

I'm wary of proxy objects mostly due to efficiency concerns, but resources that explain how to make an efficient proxy would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have figured out a good solution using generics:

```
public class IMDB
{
    public Dictionary<int, Person> people;

    public T RelatedID<T>(int id, IndexedMember<T> field) { ... }
    public List<T> IDRelatedIDs<T>(int key, IndexedMember<T> field) { ... }
    public void SetRelatedID<T>(int id, T newVal, IndexedMember<T> field) { ... }
}

public class Person
{
    // "new IndexedMember<int>()" to initialize before first access, or
    // init upon startup (using some other manifest already maintained)
    // for less verbosity.
    public static IndexedMember<int> favoriteCelebrityID;
    public static IndexedMember<string> lastName;
    public string firstName;
}

public class IndexedMember<T>
{
    // ...
}
```

If I can implement this I'll be very satisfied with it, but any improvements or alternate solutions are always welcome.